# Has NotificationHubClient.SendDirectNotificationAsync(notification, token) been deprecated?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I have a long running Azure Function that sends iOS notifications through a notification hub. The function has always used the `SendDirectNotificationAsync` method which took two parameters - the AppleNotification and the device token to send the notification to.

After working perfectly for months, I've noticed it no longer does. There are no errors in the function logs and the function still returns a Success code, but the notification does not get delivered. The activity log in the Notification Hub shows no activity - so I believe the Notification Hub is no longer even receiving the notification from the Azure Function to try and deliver.

When I attempt to search the Azure docs for the SendDirectNotificationAsync method the top search result in this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.senddirectnotificationasync But that link now returns a 404 which leads me to believe that this method has been removed.

Is this the case? If so, what is the recommended method for sending a notification through the Notification Hub to an iOS device when all you have is the device token?

Answer (score 0):

Craig, when did this start breaking for you?  August 14th or more recently?

If August 14th, a breaking change notification was added here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-functions-runtime-2-0-breaking-change-notice/

Also, can you share where you got the library from and the current version you are using?  It looks like the NuGet package updated to version 2.0.1 4 days ago.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs

Thanks.
James

Comment: This broke before August 14th and is unrelated to any changes in Azure Functions specifically . Also, there is no "library" or NuGet package being used. The NotificationHub is a configured output in the bindings for the Azure Function like this: `{
      "type": "notificationHub",
      "name": "hub",
      "hubName": "xxxxxx",
      "connection": "xxxxxx",
      "enableTestSend": true,
      "platform": "apns",
      "direction": "out"
    }`